# Question about uniform convergence on $\mathbb{Q}$ implying uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n$ continuous for all $n=1,2, \cdots $ . I'm trying to show that if ${f_n}$ is uniform convergent on $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is uniform convergent on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that since ${f_n}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{Q}$, the function $f$ to which the sequence uniformly converges on $\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$. I suspect that I might need to use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm pretty stumped on this problem, but I'm interested in trying to work through it mostly on my own so I would appreciate some hints rather than a full proof of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that Cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence is that 
$$\{f_n\} \text{ uniformly convergent on } E \iff \forall\epsilon>0, \exists N,\forall n,m>N,\forall x\in E, |f_n(x)-f_{m}(x)|\le\epsilon.$$
Now that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f_n-f_m$ is continuous, the condition 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}, |f_n(x)-f_{m}(x)|\le\epsilon\implies \forall x\in\mathbb{R},|f_n(x)-f_{m}(x)|\le\epsilon.$$
Thus, for continuous functions $\{f_n\}$, uniform convergence on $\mathbb{Q}$ implies uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To the proposer: Let $g_{n,m}(x)=f_n(x)-f_m(x).$ Then $g_{n,m}$ is continuous so $(g_{n,m})^{-1}S$ is closed when $S$ is closed.  So if $(g_{n,m})^{-1}[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\supseteq \Bbb Q$ then $(g_{n,m})^{-1}[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\supseteq \overline {\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R.$